# Jsonb Column extract rows

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to postgres and wondering someone can point me in the direction of how to expand the below column into rows.  I am able to do this when the data is an array using jsonb_array_elements however the below is an object?

**Column**

```
{
  "023f8420-aca8-4f8f-9aa9-37f59d178b0f": {
    "value": "364.0",
    "method": "credit_card",
    "package": "premium",
    "price_id": "909eaf97-7147-4e05-8d62-bf59579ca618",
    "frequency": "yearly",
    "product_id": 2767,
    "product_type": "Category"
  },
  "5a1a5483-f587-4ade-838f-2d8e25ca74eb": {
    "value": "450.0",
    "method": "credit_card",
    "package": "premium",
    "price_id": "511ff0d7-2efe-4fea-a483-b763ecbb40dd",
    "frequency": "yearly",
    "product_id": 2204,
    "product_type": "Category"
  }
}
```

Have managed to do something like this so far

```
 SELECT 
    cart_items.*,
    value ->> 'package' as product_id
    value ->> 'method' as payment_method,
    value ->> 'price_id' as price_id
FROM schema.cart_transactions ct,
jsonb_each(ct.cart_contents ) as cart_items
left outer join schema.product_prices pp
    on (cart_items.value ->> 'price_id')::int = pp.id
where 
    stripe_payment_intent_id is not null
```

**Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE cart_transactions (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    cart_order_id int4 NULL,
    payment_method_type varchar NULL,
    package int4 NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp NOT NULL,
    payment_response json NULL,
    status int4 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    uuid uuid NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    registration_fee_charged bool NULL,
    cart_contents jsonb NULL DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb,
    instalment_plan_id uuid NULL,
    stripe_payment_intent_id varchar NULL,
    CONSTRAINT cart_transactions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE product_prices (
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    priceable_id uuid NULL,
    code varchar NULL,
    price numeric(8,2) NULL,
    billing_frequency int4 NULL,
    payment_method int4 NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp NOT NULL,
    package int4 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    priceable_type varchar NULL,
    variable_pricing bool NULL DEFAULT true,
    deleted bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    deleted_at timestamp NULL,
    price_updated_at timestamp NULL,
    CONSTRAINT product_prices_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Just use `jsonb_each`?

Comment: How would one then do a join on say value ->> 'price_id' on another table?

Comment: Have updated question now

Comment: Looks like you're done, does it not work?

Comment: You might want to use `(value ->> 'price_id')::int` though

Comment: No I keep getting:  syntax error at or near "value"

Comment: Seems you are missing the `ON` keyword for your join

Comment: Good spoting.  Still no luck though.  Have updated the example code

Comment: Please also post the error message you're getting, and optimally also the table definitions (their create statements)

Comment: Have posted table.  The exact error is "SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "value"
  Position: 63"

Comment: Ok its probably becuase is a UUID colum

Comment: Could you please minimize your table DDL to the minimum necessary to show the problem. It's not easily possible to generate some examples to test your problem. AFAIK you need only one column, correct?